# How to do fine control of view rendering in Pyramid

Tags: pyramid, mako

The conventional way seems fine:

```
@view_config(route_name='new', renderer='new.mako')
    return {'tasks': tasks}
```

But sometimes I may need to have fine control of what I am rendering, ie I may render **different views** subject to conditions. See this pseudocode:

```
@view_config(route_name='new')
def new_view(request):
    if request.att == something:
        one_dict = ...
        a = render( "new.mako", one_dict)
    else:
        another_dict = ...
        a = render( "new_special.mako", one_dict)
    return a
```

How do I render an arbitary template myself with Pyramid's Mako engine and return it as a response?

Comment: How about using [`render_to_response()`](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/1.5-branch/api/renderers.html#pyramid.renderers.render_to_response)?

Comment: @PiotrDobrogost please put it as answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`render_to_response()` renderer](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/1.5-branch/api/renderers.html#pyramid.renderers.render_to_response) here:

> Using the renderer `renderer_name` (a template or a static renderer), render the value (or set of values) using the result of the renderer's `__call__` method (usually a string or Unicode) as the response body.

For your code that'd be:

```
@view_config(route_name='new')
def new_view(request):
    if request.att == something:
        one_dict = ...
        a = render_to_response("new.mako", one_dict)
    else:
        another_dict = ...
        a = render_to_response("new_special.mako", one_dict)
    return a
```

or perhaps:

```
@view_config(route_name='new')
def new_view(request):
    if request.att == something:
        renderer = "new.mako"
    else:
        renderer = "new_special.mako"
    return render_to_response(renderer, values)
```